# How do I get Node Exports to work properly?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Node Noob here...experimenting with Exports and Require...

I have a Javascript file named GoogleHomePage.js that contains this code:

```
var GoogleHomePage = function (){
    module.exports.Home = function () {
        var homepage = "http://www.google.com";
        browser.get(homepage);

    }
}
```

I then want to use require from another file named FileB.js like this:

```
var g = require("./GoogleHomePage.js");
g.Home();
```

When g.Home() is run, I get Undefined... Yet, when I look at g in the debugger, I can see that it has a function named Home...

If I type in g.Home in console window it shows me the function code...

How do I get g.Home() to execute?  Is this happening because there is no g object e.g.  var x = new g() or would it be var x = new GoogleHomePage()?

Comment: What do you mean you get Undefined?

Comment: Why are you setting `Home` inside another function?

Comment: @thefourtheye I'm not trying to set home in another function, I'm trying to call it from another file so that the browser will navigate to http://www.google.com...

Comment: *"I'm not trying to set home in another function"* but that's exactly what you're doing. remove the first and last lines of that snippet.

Comment: The first code snippet is in file1, the second is in file2.  How would I call file1.Home from file2?  That's my question... I'm sure I'm doing something incorrect or maybe not...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are wrapping your export in a function and it is not going to work right. Try this instead:

GoogleHomePage.js:

```
module.exports = function() {
    var homepage = "http://www.google.com";
    browser.get(homepage);

}
```

FileB.js

```
var googleHomePage = require("./GoogleHomePage.js");
googleHomePage();
```

So export the function directly -- there is no need to wrap it in that odd `var GoogleHomePage = function (){ ... }` construct.

If you want to export multiple things in `GoogleHomePage`, you can export an object with properties like so:

GoogleHomePage.js:

```
module.exports = {
  Home: function() {
    var homepage = "http://www.google.com";
    browser.get(homepage);
  },

  SomethingElse: function() {
    // ...
  }
};
```

Then FileB.js would look like:

```
var googleHomePage = require("./GoogleHomePage.js");
googleHomePage.Home();
```

Or you could do:

```
var home = require("./GoogleHomePage.js").Home;
home();
```

Comment: Thanks! Let me give it a shot.

Comment: @JohnPeters You can find out more about this by googling "nodejs commonjs". For example, https://egghead.io/lessons/nodejs-commonjs-basics-introduction or http://elegantcode.com/2011/02/04/taking-baby-steps-with-node-js-commonjs-and-creating-custom-modules/

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
var GoogleHomePage = function (){
    module.exports.Home = function () {
        var homepage = "http://www.google.com";
        browser.get(homepage);

    }
}
```

you want

```
module.exports = function () {
    var homepage = "http://www.google.com";
    browser.get(homepage);
}
```

`module` is a variable local to the module in question, and `exports` is a property of that object.  The function `GoogleHomePage` never gets called in your code, so your assignment never runs.

When you require the module, just do

```
var g = require('./GoogleHomePage');
g();
```

The `.js` is unnecessary.